# ubuntu 12.10 resets keybindings

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and I want to map the show-desktop keybinding to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. I tried to configure it in Compiz configuration manager, in the system properties-keyboard configuration and in dconf-editor but without success. After each reboot the value of the dconf entry is reset to the default value `<primary><super><d>`.

I really don't know what to do now :P

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate your problem in 12.10 if I change the setting through *System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts*.

This is probably related to [Bug #936840](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/936840)  about the change in Gnome from using `<ctrl>` to using `<primary>`. Note that the setting in System Settings is given as `Ctrl+Super+D`, so the setting is probably no longer going through correctly.

When I left the setting in System Settings alone and made the change from CompizConfig or Dconf, the change held across reboots. Note that these two programs, use `<Control><Primary><Super>d`, so they apparently are able to hook the settings daemon correctly.

If you are still having trouble, try resetting System Settings to the default, rebooting, and then making the change from CompizConfig.