# Why Ubuntu 13.04 cannot keep some shortcut configuration?

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys

Normally, i like to set "close window" shortcut from `Alt+F4` to `Ctrl+q` because it's more convenient. but when i restart my computer my setting become `Alt+F4` again.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Also see the answer at [resets keybindings](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278096/ubuntu-12-10-resets-keybindings/280380#280380)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line to change the setting like this:

`gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/window_keybindings/close -t string "<Control>q"`

This should change the setting a keep it through a reboot. I have not tested it myself but if it does not work you can always add the command to your your startup commands.

One way to do this is to add the command to your `/etc/rc.local` file.
Add the above command to the file just before the `exit 0` entry. Make sure that the file ends with `exit 0`.

Comment: EDIT: added info about the rc.local file

Comment: sorry. I know that you can use the `dconf-editor` utility to look at the available keybindings. Open the utility an then navigate to: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`

Comment: That doesn't actually work for me, but that is solely because I am using Lubuntu.  Would you add this information into your answer and then delete your comments (for the sake of keeping the answer cleaner)?  Thanks!